# Should a server always send a JSON object as an http response?

Tags: json, node.js, http, express, retrofit

I'm working on a node.js server using express and a android native app, using Retrofit 1.9.
For a login API that returns only a true/false answer to the client, should JSON still be used?

As I see it, the server has only to send a status code response:

```
if(isLegal) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    dbConnector.updateUser(token);
}
else{
    console.log('Token is not legal');
    res.sendStatus(403);
}
```

But the Retrofit framework tries to convert the response to JSON, which makes me think I must send a JSON object with the answer, though it seems weird.

My retrofit restClient:

```
public class RestClient {
private static final String URL = SessionDetails.getInstance().serverAddress;

private retrofit.RestAdapter restAdapter;
private ServerAPI serverAPI;

public RestClient() {

    restAdapter = new retrofit.RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    serverAPI = restAdapter.create(ServerAPI.class);
}

public ServerAPI getService() {
    return serverAPI;
}
```

}

And usage:

```
            restClient.getService().login(token.getToken(), token.getUserId(), new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Void aVoid, Response response) {
                Log.d("Chooser", "Successful login on server.");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Chooser", "Login failed on server.");
            }
        });
```

Using it as it is results with the following error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

There are many topics on this issue but no certain answer about the correct (or better) method to use.

Any ideas about the best implementation in these cases?

Comment: Retrofit uses Gson as json library and it will try to parse any object that is received from server.

Comment: That's for sure. But in case of non JSON response, there will be an exception thrown.

Comment: You can create simple class for this scenario. Maybe in future, this login process will be extended.

Comment: @Bobcat100 Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815523/should-a-server-always-send-a-json-object-as-an-http-response/39816807#39816807) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to make sure they are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an empty body with your HTTP response is perfectly legal and some clients may care only about the response status but some clients may expect to get a response so sending a body never hurts and sometimes may be useful.

You can include a JSON response in addition to the HTTP response status:

```
// Express 4.x:
res.status(403).json({error: 'Token is not legal'});

// Express 3.x:
res.json(403, {error: 'Token is not legal'});
```

Such an error message can be very useful for the client development. You can get 403 for many reasons, illegal token, expired token, a legal not expired token but for the wrong user that doesn't have some privilege - adding a specific error message in addition to the HTTP response code can tell the client what exactly went wrong and allows the client-side code to show a better error message to the user.

Also, note that `true` and `false` are also valid JSON.